# Java Native Interface : Object Passing

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I was trying to implement a simple object passing code but there was a error by the compiler.

Error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: count  at
>   objectpassing.ObjectPassing.changeCount(Native Method)

Here is my Java Code

```
public class ObjectPassing {
    static{
        System.load("out.dll");
    }
    int count=10;
    String message="hi";
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ObjectPassing ob=new ObjectPassing();
        ObjectPassing.changeCount();
        System.out.println("Number in java"+ob.count);
        System.out.println(ob.message);
    }
    private static native void changeCount();
}
```

My C code is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include "jnivg.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_objectpassing_ObjectPassing_changeCount
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass o)
{
    jclass  tc=(*env)->GetObjectClass(env,o);
    jfieldID fid=(*env)->GetFieldID(env,tc,"count","I");
    jint n=(*env)->GetIntField(env,o,fid);
    printf("Number in c= %d",n);
    n=200;
    (*env)->SetIntField(env,o,fid,n);
}
```

Comment: You're calling `GetStaticFieldID` on `count`, but `count` is not `static`

Comment: Tried changing it. Still the same error

Comment: "Tried changing it." - Changing *what*?

Comment: I corrected the `GetStaticFieldID` to `GetFieldID`. @JacobG.

Comment: Yes @JacobG. No luck.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer below. Static Variables can only be used with static methods. Either change all the variables to static, or have a non static method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get the value of the **non-static field** from a **static method**, which is impossible due to common sense, regardless whether your method is native or not.

You should either make your `count` field static and use `GetStaticFieldID` and `GetStaticIntField` functions with it. Or make your `changeCount` method non-static so it will have a `jobject` parameter instead of `jclass` which you then will be able to use with `GetIntField` function.